# Question on Null space and Dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

> If the null space of a $5\times6$ matrix $A$ is $4$-dimensional, what is the dimension of the row space of $A$?

I think this has to do with the rank nullity theorem, but I'm not sure how exactly you would prove the answer. Thanks

Comment: You're right that the question has to do with the rank nullity theorem. If the nullspace of $A$ has dimension $4$, then what is the rank of $A$?

Comment: Wouldn't the rank be 4?

Comment: If $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix, then the rank of $A$ plus the nullity of $A$ is equal to $n$. So the rank of $A$ in this case is $6-4=2$.

Comment: Now how does the rank relate to the dimension of the row space of $A$?

Comment: The dimension of the row space would just be the rank, so it would just be 2? And what exactly does the nullity of A refer to? the nullspace?

Comment: The nullity of $A$ is the dimension of the nullspace of $A$. And yes, the rank of $A$ is equal to the dimension of the row space.

Comment: Ok I got it now. Thanks for clarifying